# How to copy the latest file based on time using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy the newest file based on the time, I tried the below script, but it is copying all the files not the latest file:

```
 FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR "%FILE1%\CC*.txt" /B /O:-D /s') DO COPY %%I C:\Hyp\New\
```

For ex.:

> ```
> xyz1.txt -- 4:23
> xyz2.txt -- 4:25
> xyz3.txt -- 4:30
> ```

But I need to copy only the latest file i.e. `4:30`, kindly assist (not all the files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. Instead of copying inside the bode of the `FOR` loop, store the file in a variable (say `LATEST`), which will be overwritten every iteration. After the loop has finished, the newest file is stored in the variable, supposing you define the sort order like `/O:D` (oldest file listed first).

This is the fixed script:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR "%FILE1%\CC*.txt" /B /A:-D /T:W /O:D /S') DO SET "LATEST=%%~I"
COPY "%LATEST%" "C:\Hyp\New\"
```

I added the filter `/A:-D` in order to enumerate files only (no directories).
Furthermore, I added the `/T` option which allows to choose which file date to use: state `W` for last modification (default), `C` for creation, or `A` for last access.